# Concatenate string and result of expression inside a powershell command

Tags: powershell, windows-10, concatenation

I have this code

```
powershell -Command "(gc "E:\Desktop\Nuova\anag.xml") -replace '<Revocato>true</Revocato>', (Get-Date).AddDays(-1).ToString('MM-dd-yyyy') | set-content "E:\Desktop\Nuova\anag.xml""
```

That returns `03-07-2019`

But I want it to return `<Revocato>03-07-2019</Revocato>`

I tried different approaches, like using as second replace parameter `'<Revocato>{0}</Revocato>' -f ((Get-Date).AddDays(-1).ToString('MM-dd-yyyy'))` and few other ideas, but nothing return the result I want. Any help please?

Comment: Have you tried using an actual [XML parser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/powershell+xml)?

Comment: Does this help
'<Revocato>true</Revocato>' -replace '<Revocato>true</Revocato>', "<Revocato>$((Get-Date).AddDays(-1).ToString('MM-dd-yyyy'))</Revocato>"
Else, can you share the XML?

Comment: (gc "revocato.xml") -replace "(?m)^.*(<Revocato>.*)(true.*)(</Revocato>.*)$", ("`$1~$((Get-Date).AddDays(-1).ToString('MM-dd-yyyy'))~`$3") -replace '~',''

Comment: @f6a4 thanks it works! :)
Make it an answer so I can mark it as solution